# Problem with intersects operator in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, intersection

I have this table below

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume (
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null );
```

I am trying to make this query:

```
SELECT id 
    FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume 
    WHERE box'((15,47),(16,48))' ?# coordinates;
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: box ?# path
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I find if a path is intersecting with a box?

Comment: Maybe the overlap operator : `SELECT box('((15,47),(16,48))')::polygon && path::polygon` ? But beware, it can be not exact ...

Comment: I have solved it with this 
`SELECT *
  FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume 
  WHERE path(polygon(box'((15,47),(16,48))')) ?# coordinates or polygon(box'((15,47),(16,48))') @> polygon(coordinates);`

Comment: Post this solution for your question, in Stack, you can self-answer.